# CSS Tooltips not showing on IE, Safari, works on FireFox

Tags: html, css, tooltip, imagemap

Still in the works but noticed an issue that i cant figure out.. Im pretty good at dabbling around and figuring things out, but do not have any formal education in web development so please be patient with me.

The [site](http://www.skilledgraphics.com/pawshie/index.php/explore-pawville/ruffway-hills) I am working on -  has an image map with tooltips when you hover specific areas. Works great in FF, doesnt show in IE and Safari.. Any idea on what I am missing? Or a better way to implement? Trying to stay away from JavaScript. Thanks!

My Code

```css
map { position: relative; }

area + span { position: absolute; margin-left: -9999em; }

area:hover + span {

    position: absolute; /* can only be positioned relative to the entire map, not the area */

    left: 100px;

    top: -700px;

    z-index: 5000;

    color: #ffffff;

    background: #ec287a;

    border: 1px solid #ffffff;

    margin: 0;

    width: 600px;

    padding: 20px;

}
```

```html
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="images/ruffwaytext.png" alt="" /></p>
<center><img src="http://www.skilledgraphics.com/pawshie/images/ruffway.png" width="1200" height="670" usemap="#planetmap" /></center>
<map name="planetmap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="377,309,835,615" alt="Ruffway Hills" <a href="ruff" /><span><center><strong>RUFFWAY HILLS<br>Tottie loves stargazing here and pointing out constellations to her friends</strong></center></span>
</map>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your img tag like this:

```
<img src="http://www.skilledgraphics.com/pawshie/images/ruffway.png" width="1200" height="670" usemap="#planetmap" title="tooltip text goes here blah blah blah" />
```

The title attribute included in your < img/> tag should display hovertext of what you include in the quotes. It's supported by IE, FFox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera.

Comment: yes, but that's not what i am trying to do. (should have explained my desired outcome better).. That's just a basic default tootip, im using customized tootips using css.... I actually found another way to accomplish this by defining the hotspots in css, not sure why the above didnt work but im good now.